# Sql query group and read one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

Client:

```
ID int
Name varchar
```

Orders:

```
ID int
ClientID int
OrderDetails
```

One client may has many orders.

How can I obtain dataset for all clients and only one order for this client?

Group by client and add to this group one order

Example:

Client:

```
ID| Name  |
--+-------+
1 | John  |
2 | Peter |
3 | Andry |
```

Orders:

```
ID| ClientID | OrderDetails |
--+----------+--------------+
1 | 1        |  Done        |   
2 | 1        |  Progress    |
3 | 2        |  Progress    |
4 | 2        |  Done        |
5 | 2        |  Fail        |
```

Expected result:

```
ClientID | Name | OrderID | OrderDetails |
---------+------+---------+--------------+
    1    | John |   1     |   Done       |
    2    | Peter|   2     |   Progress   |
    3    | Andry|   None  |    None      |
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect results?

Comment: @D-Shih posted example

Comment: Thank for your sample data, but could you explain what's the logic from your expect result?

Comment: What is your criteria for which order to show when you have more than one?  The most recent?

Comment: @Hambone it could be the frist row. There is no special logic for what order should be in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If which order doesn't matter, something like this would work:

```
select distinct on (c.id)
  c.id, c.name, o.id as order_id, o.order_details
from
  client c
  left join orders o on
    c.id = o.client_id
order by
  c.id
```

If you change your mind, and the order *does* matter, just change the order by to include the field that determines which order you pick.

Alternately, you can list all orders with something like this:

```
select
  c.id, c.name,
  array_agg (o.id) as order_ids,
  array_agg (o.order_details) as details
from
  client c
  left join orders o on
    c.id = o.client_id
group by
  c.id, c.name
```

Comment: Looks what I need, thanks! But is there an approach to add count of orders for client?
In my case, for example, it will be: 2 for John, 3 for Piter and 0 for Andry

Comment: In the second example (with the group by), you can add `count (*) as order_count` in the select portion...  really if you are doing counts, you need the group by clause.  If the rest of the query is no bueno because of that and you really only want one order number, that can be accomplished -- just clarify if you need to